# Is the Azure Functions Durable createCheckStatusResponse secure enough to share in public?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am currently playing with Azure Functions Durable functions

Is the response given from `createCheckStatusResponse` safe to publish to the public at large, or should it only be consumed within the application?

I am particularly worried that the `code` parameter doesn't appear to change from instance to instance, so I'm wary of sharing it in public. For example, on my local development system, I get a response that looks like:

```json
{
  "id": "c21cf6e94d3f4b0c9cd9585cff452b2a",
  "statusQueryGetUri": "http://localhost:7075/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/c21cf6e94d3f4b0c9cd9585cff452b2a?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=qRXSFqgiAsC4fqrCjIGjGl3nyr1vLRYjJu9meCVeyEMrAzFuSJdBSw==",
    ...
}
```

I'm worried that exposing that `&code=qRXSFqgiAsC4fqrCjIGjGl3nyr1vLRYjJu9meCVeyEMrAzFuSJdBSw==` bit to a third party might be unsafe if this were a production environment. This code does not appear to change at all between different instances, or runs of the function environment, and I suspect it may be some sort of code that may give access to the underlying storage.

One alternative I've considered is creating my own `status` function that returns the status for the given instance_ID, using a new Durable Functions Client to look up that status, and trusting that function's security to protect me from outside. My reasoning is that at worst, as the `code` parameter is fixed, it's no less secure than the built-in method, and it doesn't expose a potentially secret code to the public.

Comment: Please link to documentation for the method you're using that accepts a `code` parameter, because I don't know any versions of `CreateCheckStatusResponse` that take such an argument.

Comment: I must have explained badly. I'm using [the python createCheckStatusResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions-durable/azure.durable_functions.durableorchestrationclient?view=azure-python#azure-durable-functions-durableorchestrationclient-create-check-status-response) which doesn't take `code` as a parameter. However, the URLs it returns do have `code` as a parameter. e.g. `http://localhost:7075/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/c21cf6e94d3f4b0c9cd9585cff452b2a?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=qRXSFqgiAsC4fqrCjIGjGl3nyr1vLRYjJu9meCVeyEMrAzFuSJdBSw==`

Comment: I'm specifically worrying about whether I should be passing that URL to a third party, or whether exposing that `&code=qRXSFqgiAsC4fqrCjIGjGl3nyr1vLRYjJu9meCVeyEMrAzFuSJdBSw==` bit is unsafe. I've updated the question to reflect this.